# android if statement in Custom Adopter

Tags: android, if-statement

i made star ImageView when i click change the img when i click it again its change to anther one . 
the problem with ImageView  in list view i did all good but when i make if statement in custom adapter the if statement don't work and its change random img star
i just want change specific ImageView  after the IF statement .

```
 final ImageView ima= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagestar);

 String path = "/storage/emulated/0/data/" + m.getTitle() + ".txt";
  File f = new File(path);       
      if (f.getName().equals(m.getTitle() + ".txt"))
       {
        File file2 = new File("/storage/emulated/0/data/" + m.getTitle() + ".txt");
        if(file2.exists())      
        {
             System.out.println(f.getName());
             ima.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);

        }
       }
```

thanks all.

Comment: why don't you debug your codes and see what exactly happens?

Comment: i don't get error its just if statement don't do what i need

Comment: post your full custom adapter

Comment: this is http://textuploader.com/k8iz

Comment: remove this  i was trying some thing         ima.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_normal);

Comment: thanks i found the problem :P